# Difference between CROSS JOIN and INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

As I understand it, `CROSS JOIN` is essentially a cross product which produces a Cartesian Product. Are `INNER JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `OUTER JOIN` Cartesian products as well except for fact that they don't produce duplicates and have some condition applied to them?

Thanks!

***Note: I don't believe this is a duplicate***. The link does not elaborate on the difference to the detail that I was looking for. It's left up to the reader to dig through & infer the differences. The answer I've provided below will hopefully save the reader some time.

Answer (score -1):

> The JOIN operation can be specified as a CARTESIAN PRODUCT operation
>   followed by a SELECT operation.
>
> ...
>
> The result of the JOIN is a relation Q with n + m attributes Q(A1, A2,
>   ... , An, B1, B2, ... , Bm) in that order; Q has one tuple for each
>   combination of tuples—one from R and one from S—whenever the
>   combination satisfies the join condition. This is the main difference
>   between CARTESIAN PRODUCT and JOIN. In JOIN, only combinations of
>   tuples satisfying the join condition appear in the result, whereas in
>   the CARTESIAN PRODUCT all combinations of tuples are included in the
>   result. The join condition is specified on attributes from the two
>   relations R and S and is evaluated for each combination of tuples.
>   Each tuple combination for which the join condition evaluates to TRUE
>   is included in the resulting relation Q as a single combined tuple.

Source: Fundamentals of Database Systems (7th edition), Elmasri